# Understanding flatMap and Map

Tags: scala, functional-programming, option-type

In exercise 4.4 of the book *Functional Programming in Scala* (ISBN: 978-1617290657), we need to run through a List of Options, and concatenate the values in those Options into a single Option containing a List. If the initial List contains a None Option, the final Option should be None as well.

Function Signature

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]]
```

Sample 1

```
scala> sequence(List(Some(3), Some(5), Some(1)))
Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(3, 5, 1))
```

Sample 2

```
scala> sequence(List(Some(3), None, Some(1)))
Option[List[Int]] = None
```

This is a solution that I found online:

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = a match {
  case Nil => Some(Nil)
  case h :: t => h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map (hh :: _))
}
```

Despite my best efforts at understanding this implementation (by writing the function trace on paper), I'm unable to get an intuitive grasp of this function. I am able to understand what map and flatMap means in isolation, but not in the context of this function.

Is there another way to look at the problem, and through that perspective, derive the code above intuitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify the problem, here is what is being asked:

> Write a function sequence that combines a list of Options into one Option containing a list of all the Some values in the original list. If the original list contains None even once, the result of the function should be None; otherwise the result should be Some with a list of all the values.

In other words, `sequence` evaluates sequentially each Option in the list passed in argument. If a None is found while evaluating this sequence, the functions stops and returns a None without processing the rest of the list.

`flatMap` allows the chaining of two computations among which one depends on the result of the other:

```
Option(42).flatMap(i => Option(i + 1))
```

The second Option (`Option(i + 1)`) created, depends on the result (`i`) obtained by the first Option. One interesting thing about `map` and `flatMap`, is that given the function `f: A => Option[A]`, `map` keeps the intermediate results of the computation chain while `flatMap` skips them. This is why:

```
val am: Option[Option[A]] = Option(a).map(a => f(a))
val af: Option[A] = Option(a).flatMap(a => f(a))
```

Back to our problem and having this in mind, the function `sequence` can be expressed as the list of the results obtained by each computation chained sequentially, wrapped in a computation of the same kind.

```
def sequence[A](a: List[Option[A]]): Option[List[A]] = a match {
    case Nil => Some(Nil)
    case h :: t => h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map (hh :: _))
}
```

In order to understand this implementation, you need to understand how recursion works. Stop thinking about how each element of this code evaluates (the how) and try to focus on the what (just like in Math). Given that:

```
h flatMap (_ => sequence(t))
```

represents the last computation evaluated in the sequence passed in parameter, once all previous computations have been evaluated successfully. Therefore:

```
h flatMap (hh => sequence(t) map (hh :: _))
```

is the accumulation of each intermediary result obtained while evaluating this chain of computation. I suggest you to look at the `traverse` function and to the concept of `Applicative` in Functional Programming. These two notions are exactly what defines `sequence`.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

So... Your function is supposed to take `elem: Option[A]` elements one by from the `optionList: List[Option[A]]` and accumulate them into an `acc: Option[List[A]]`.

Now, the first case `case Nil => Some(Nil)` should be pretty easy to understand. As it says that if the input `List[Option[A]]` is `Nil` or `empty` then just return an option of empty list which is `Some(Nil)`.

As for the second part, It can be more clearly written as follows,

```
case head :: tail => h.flatMap(headValue => {
  val tailResult = sequence(tail)
  tailResult.map(tailResultValue => headValue :: tailResultValue)
)
```

it takes the `head: Option[A]` at the head of `list` and it then recursively applies the `sequence` function to the rest of the list `tail` to get `tailResult` which will be an `Option[List[A]]`. Now, it maps the value of this `tailResult` which is the `List[A]` and appends the value of current `head` to it.